# Opening a file opens the folder the file is in, not the file itself

Tags: nautilus, firefox, unity-dash

Whenever I try to open a file (such as an .odt, or .doc) from say, the Dash or the Firefox Downloads, Ubuntu 11.10 opens Nautilus to the the folder where the file is, rather than just going to the application and loading the file straight away.

In previous releases, when I clicked on a downloaded file, it just went straight to LibreOffice, and it was fine. This is adding a superfluous step in the process.

How do I associate the correct extensions?

Answer (score 7):

There is an easier way to fix this, even with exo installed (I use unity AND xfce4-panel so I needed both).

Open `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` in an editor (make a backup just in case!). Remove the following lines:

```
x-scheme-handler/file=exo-file-manager.desktop
x-scheme-handler/trash=exo-file-manager.desktop
```

Save, and it should work now.

Some users will need to make exactly the same changes to `/usr/share/xubuntu/applications/defaults.list` as well. The lines can be commented out by adding `#` at the beginning of each. The fix works after logging in again.

Comment: I liked this one and use it. Because exo is needed by some xubuntu stuff. +1

Answer (score 3):

uninstall exo

...HOWEVER I believe this breaks xfce, so this will not work if you're using xfce as well as gnome. if you don't need xfce this works. in my case the following packages plus their dependencies:

```
Completely removed the following packages:
exo-utils
libexo-1-0
libexo-common
libexo-helpers
```

very annoying problem and I had a very hard time finding the answer. finally found this : https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=882193 - if you're looking for a better solution that has more explanation.

I believe this happened when I installed xfce to try it out.

Comment: Thanks Alex. As it turned out, I just did a complete re-install (there were other problems emerging anyway). But hopefully your suggestion helps somebody else in the future. :) I think you're right though - I'd installed xfce, and the problem emerged after that. I just hadn't seen the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Similar question. Try this solution which is there in below URL.

[Can't open .xlsx file with LibreOffice](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68036/cant-open-xlsx-file-with-libreoffice)

Comment: Not quite. It's not that it's opening the file with the wrong program. It's that it's opening nautilus first as the WAY to THEN open the file.

When I click-to-open a word/odt file, I just want to cut out the Nautilus "middle-man", and just go straight to LibreOffice. Going into the "Properties>Open_With" won't fix that.

Comment: i had also faced the same problem.but once manually opened now its worked fine

Comment: Can you define "manually opened" for me? If I click at the .odt or .doc in Nautilus, yeah, it works great. But if I try to open via the Dash or Firefox, it doesn't. I just checked opening a doc from the "Saved Files" part of Thunderbird, and yep, it does it there too.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, yet libexo was never installed. The rather brutal way of deleting the `.local` folder in my home directory solved it.